# Borrow mutable and immutable reference in the same block

Tags: data-structures, hashmap, hashtable, rust

I'm trying to implement my own naive HashMap/HashTable data structure in Rust. The first step is to create a table of type `Vec<&mut Bucket>` where `type Bucket = Vec<i64>`.

I'm having problems actually filling the table with data... I'm reading 1 000 000 integers from an input file and storing them into 100 000 buckets. For each number from the input, I assign a random bucket. I first check if the bucket already exists and if it does, I push the number onto the bucket. Otherwise, I create the bucket and store it in the table.

I have encountered two problems while doing this:

The **first problem** is that I get an error saying `'b' does not live long enough` while the creating the bucket. How do I preserve the bucket even after it's scope has ended?

The **second problem** is that I'm borrowing the `table` both mutably and immutably but I'm not sure how to avoid this.

```
use std::env;
// other libs...

extern crate rand;
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng};

type Bucket = Vec<i64>;

fn main() {
    let mut rng = thread_rng();

    let mut nums = // read 1 million i64s, ie. vec![4253564645, 2394887235, ...] 
    println!("input consumed!");

    let mut table: Vec<&mut Bucket> = Vec::new();

    for x in nums.iter() { 
        let key: usize = rng.gen_range(0, 99999);
        println!("{}", key);

        if let Some(mut b) = table.get(key) { // <-- immutable borrow
            b.push(x);
        } else {
            let mut b = vec![x]; // <-- `b` does not live long enough
            table.insert(key, &mut b); //  <-- mutable borrow
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to run the example the whole thing is here: https://gist.github.com/neektza/f96d8bf92ee66f1c1703

P.S.
I'm using Rust 1.0.0

Comment: Please make your example code a [MCVE](/help/mcve). For example, you don't need to include *any* randomness to reproduce your error. Additionally, you can just provide a *single* value to `nums`. Make your code small, make it reproduce one problem, and ideally make it run on the [Playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/). Please have the curtesy to spend a bit of time when asking in order to save the time of many people who will read this to learn or attempt to answer.

Comment: You are asking two questions (another thing to please not do). I've marked this as a duplicate of one of them. For your other question, please review [the multitude of questions about that error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+does+not+live+long+enough) and potentially ask a new question, detailing (a) why your problem is different or (b) what you don't understand about them.